# Remove characters from specific positions in text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a text file that looks like below.

```
Domain Certificate
Valid from: Tue Jul 12 05:30:00 IST 2022 
Valid upto: Thu Jan 05 05:29:59 IST 2023
Subject Alternative Names
SAN: yahoo.com
SAN: tw.rd.yahoo.com
SAN: s.yimg.com
SAN: mbp.yimg.com


1st Intermediate Certificate
Valid from: Tue Oct 22 17:30:00 IST 2013 
Valid upto: Sun Oct 22 17:30:00 IST 2028
```

For each line that contains "Valid from" and "Valid upto", I need to remove characters from specific location and output to be in the format **Valid from: Jul 12 2022** or **Valid upto: Jan 05 2023**

I need to do this across the text file.

Also, if anybody can help modify all lines containing SAN: and help adding quotes in the domain names, like **SAN: "yahoo.com"**

Comment: Can we see your attempt at solving this problem with [tag:powershell]?

Comment: If i pass the text via a variable, I have the command. Need to do it across the file.
$text= 'Tue May 17 23:43:28 IST 2023'
$new = $text.remove(11,13).Remove(0,4)
Write-Output $new

The output is May 17 2023

Comment: For the SAN thing, no success unfortunately

Comment: Please add this information to your question instead of in the comment section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-File` parameter to read your file and `-Regex` to match the lines you want to update, for there you can use the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) with more regex to update those lines:

```
$newContent = switch -File .\path\to\file.txt -Regex {
    # if the line starts with `SAN`
    '^SAN' { $_ -replace '(?<=: )|$', '"' }
    # if the line starts with `Valid from or Valid upto`
    '^Valid(?: from| upto)' { $_ -replace '(?<=: )\w+\s(\w+)\s(\d+).+\s(\d+)', '$1 $2 $3' }
    # else, output the line as-is
    Default { $_ }
}
```

Then `$newContent` can be used to save it to a new file:

```
$newContent | Set-Content path\to\newFile.txt
```

- See https://regex101.com/r/qXKnsU/1 for the first replacement (`SAN` lines).
- See https://regex101.com/r/liTAwz/2 for the second replacement (dates).

Comment: Absolutely perfect as needed. Thank you so much @Santiago, appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi @santiago, need one more help if you can